# SyntaxError: unexpected end of JSON input NODE.js

Tags: node.js, json

So i am using an API called PokeAPI, which basically gives you a pokemon's stats using its corresponding name or pokedex number. MY form is working perfectly fine but when I am requesting my informtion (using HTTP native module), i am only getting the first bits of the JSON data, not all of it, why is that?
[My server code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbISk.png)
[What error im getting from my hyper termial(highlited is incomplete data/JSON)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3uZM.png)

This is what I am actally expecting to get: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto/

Comment: For anyone to quickly come up with resolution to your issue, you should put your code snippets here in the question itself instead of linking it.

Comment: Yes, as for why you should avoid the use of images for code : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

`response` is a nodejs [stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) which emits `data` event when a chunk of the data is received. You will have to collect all the chunks in order to process the data as whole. Stream will notify that it is done receiving all the data by emitting `end` event. Once `end` is emitted, you can process all the collected chunks by concatenating them and doing `JSON.parse` on it.